# Ruby scope at the bottom level of a module

Tags: ruby, scope

I couldn't find any explanation that made sense for this.

I'm trying to figure out how to access a variable I'm creating in a module, but not inside any class, i.e.:

```
module Moddy

attr_accessor :var

var = "wibble"

  class Squiggy

    def Class_Method ()

    end

  end

end
```

I'm trying to figure out how (if it is at all possible) to access 'var' from inside the scope of 'Squiggy' as well as from the scope of the script requiring Moddy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A module is kind of like a class with *no instances*. So instance methods defined in a module are useless on their own; you need to `include` that module in a class in order to use them.

That's important because `attr_accessor :var` essentially defines two instance methods:

```
def var
  @var
end
def var= v
  @var = v
end
```

If you want `var = "wibble"` to call the instance method you just created, you need `self` to be an *instance* of `Moddy`, but in this context `self` is just `Moddy` so you're actually just creating a local variable called `var`.

If you want `Moddy` to own `var`, you need to call `attr_accessor` from the singleton class (since `Moddy` is an instance of its singleton class).

```
module Moddy
  class << self
    attr_accessor :var
  end
  self.var = "wibble"  
end
Moddy.var
# "wibble"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module Moddy

  attr_accessor :action

  def initialize
    @action= "wibble"  
  end

  class Squiggy
    include Moddy
    def initialize
      super
    end  

    def put_var
      puts @action
    end

  end

end
```

[reference: Accessing instance variables declared in ruby modules](http://www.natontesting.com/2009/09/28/accessing-instance-variables-declared-in-ruby-modules/)